# Python pandas 'correct' syntax for slicing an entire column's/series values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, syntax, slice

Given:

```py
pandas.Series([[1,2],[3,4]])
0    [1, 2]
1    [3, 4]
dtype: object
```

Using `str` namespace of Dataframe/Series its possible to get a slice of the values (rather than of the dataframe) just like [slice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice) does.
If I understand correctly that is because `slice` is actually used on each element. so it makes sense:

```py
pandas.Series([[1,2],[3,4]]).str.slice(1,2)
0    [2]
1    [4]
dtype: object
```

The thing is I expected a different syntax to perform this kind of slicing. something more meaningful, like:
`pandas.Series([[1,2],[3,4]]).iterable.slice(1,2)`
or
`pandas.Series([[1,2],[3,4]]).slice(1,2)`

Is there an alternative syntax to apply this sort of slice that's more "intuitive" rather than looking like it is "casting" the data into strings?

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

`pandas.Series([[1,2],[3,4]]).map(lambda x:x[1:2])`

which tells pandas to slice each element with it's native syntax